# YouTube API -- Can I get list of channels users are subscribed to?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new to the YouTube API. What I am trying to research is how different channels are related to one another through comments and subscriptions. I can scrape all of the comments for different videos and compare who is commenting on both videos, but would also like to see what channels all of the commenters also subscribe to. Is there a way in the YouTube API to feed it any username/id and have it return all of the channels that they subscribe to?

I tried using subscriptions.list but this seems to only work for my own account -- and there appear to be restrictions when inputting other users.